# Rethinkdb string match two arrays

Tags: arrays, rethinkdb

I have two arrays containing only strings that I would like to match.

I cannot use contains or setIntersection because I want case insensitive match to work as well.

I have tried many different ways but I have not found a working solution. I think this is the best I have came up with so far, but it does not work:

```
r.db( 'my_db' ).table( 'Table' ).hasFields( 'tags' ).filter( function( row ) { 
  return row( 'tags' ).filter( function( t ) {
    return r.expr( [ 'Foo', 'Bar', 'FooBar' ] ).filter( function( m ) {
      return t.match( '(?i)^' + m + '$' );
    } ).count().gt( 0 );
  } ).count().gt( 0 );
} );
```

the tags column is an arrays of strings. But I think the problem is that m is not a string so I cannot use it with match. But how can I convert it to a string? I have tried coerceTo but that does not work.

Any ides on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get your query to work by using `.add()` instead of `+`, for example:

```
r.expr('(?i)^').add(m).add('$')
```

You could also try something like this instead:

```
r.db('my_db').table('Table').hasFields('tags').filter(row =>
  row('tags').map(x => x.upcase()).setIntersect(['FOO', 'BAR', 'FOOBAR']).isEmpty().not())
```

Comment: Thank you, your second solution was what I ended up doing also. But I think I will change that to using add instead of + cause that feels like the proper solution.